# Fixed Cost Map Library or Service?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, maps, gis

I need mapping for an AJAX (Javascript/PHP/MySQL) project.  All the providers I researched used a tile cost model or were beyond our budget.

I'm not looking for anything fancy, just something that allows:

1. Commercial Use (for us and users of our service who use the maps)
2. Panning
3. Zooming
4. Street Layers
5. Efficiently plotting large numbers (eg: >= 1,000) of markers by GIS or zip code.
6. Adding annotations to markers (directly or via legend).

I may even be able to do without 1 or 2 if it comes down to it.

The budget for this is tight: $2,500 for an annual license or and $5,000 to buy something outright.  However, this figure may be adjusted if there's something that isn't too far out of the ballpark.

Does anyone know of anything that fits the bill (bad pun unintended)?

Also, an additional wrinkle is that the underlying tile server should be included in the price. Some excellent responses were provided so far (and I'm looking into them), but some of them are libraries only and the tile server may be a hidden cost.  It's also not always clear just what (default) tile server is used with what library.

Comment: Which option did you go with?

Comment: @JSuar: The MapQuest API.  It was neck in neck with OpenLayers, but in the end the MapQuest usage policy seemed safer/clearer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first thing that I would try is [MapQuest APIs](http://developer.mapquest.com/) with [OpenStreetMap option](http://www.openstreetmap.org/):

- It is [free of charge for commercial and non-commercial use](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/tools/getting-started/terms-overview)
- It [supports panning and zooming](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/documentation/open-sdk/javascript/v7.0/panning)
- It has [geocoding, letting you map by ZIP code](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/documentation/open-sdk/javascript/v7.0/nominatim)
- It supports [POI markers and InfoWindows](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/documentation/open-sdk/javascript/v7.0/poi), letting you supply annotations to markers on the map.

The biggest limitation that comes with using OpenStreetMap is the lack of routing services, but it is not on your "shopping list" anyway.

Comment: Is this free for commercial use?  I did not state this in my original question, so if it has the other features I requested, the bounty is yours, as I should have been more precise in my question.

Comment: MapQuest Open Services are free for commercial use, but keep in mind there is no SLA/guaranteed uptime, etc.  The terms are here: http://developer.mapquest.com/web/info/terms-of-use

Comment: @user1161318 According to the [terms page](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/tools/getting-started/terms-overview), the OpenStreetMap ("the Community Edition") is free for all application categories - public and private, paid and free, web applications and "native" apps.

Comment: @user1161318 As far as forgetting to mention things in the original question goes, it's never too late to edit your question: the beauty of this site is that nothing is cast in stone (well, almost nothing).

Comment: True, but I felt that if I forgot to add something, that's my problem, not yours.  In any case, this looks promising.  I'm going to look at it in more detail and hopefully will know for sure by next week if it's a go.  If so, that bounty's yours!  Thanks.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Ok, it's a go! I just awarded you the bounty; let me know if you have any issues with it (this is my first bounty).

Answer (score 3):

Some other solutions that might be worth investigating.

**OpenLayers** (http://openlayers.org/) appears to support what you need.

- [2-clause BSD License (also known as the FreeBSD)](https://raw.github.com/openlayers/openlayers/master/license.txt)
- [zoom and panning](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.12/examples/zoom.html)
- [plotting](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.12/examples/kml-pointtrack.html)
- [more examples here](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.12/examples/)

**Leaflet** (http://leafletjs.com/) looks promising. Looks like it relies on the [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) option.

- [Zoom buttons, Panning animation, GeoJSON layers,](http://leafletjs.com/features.html)
- [Attribution-ShareAlike 2.0 Generic license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/)

Also, [here's a comparison](http://www.ohloh.net/p/compare?project_0=OpenLayers&project_1=Leaflet) of the two above solutions.

Hopefully, these help in your search for the optimal solution.

---

***EDIT 0***

**MapBox** ([http://mapbox.com](http://mapbox.com/)) looks like a pretty cool pay solution, that [looks to be within your budget](http://mapbox.com/plans/). It appears to support everything you need and more.

---

***EDIT 1***

I performed some more searching and found the following.

- **Modest Maps** - http://modestmaps.com/
- **Custom Build** - Build it yourself? [SO user provides basic explanation.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2952376/1085891)

  > My personal opinion would be to use the effective "standard" OSS
  >   libraries that form this type of stack.
  >
  > OSGEO has a bunch of resources for exactly this.
  >
  > - PostGIS (database)
  > - Apache (webserver)
  > - MapServer (WMS compliant GIS server)
  > - OpenStreetMap (the maps you'll need)
  > - OpenScales or OpenLayers
  > - (Flex or JS API) Total cost: a few hours of setup.
- **Polymaps** - http://polymaps.org/
- **CloudMade** - http://cloudmade.com/; [pricing](http://cloudmade.com/select/web); [SO user feedback on the company](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2304051/1085891)
- **Google Maps** - Not sure why it wasn't already mentioned, but Google maps (http://www.google.com/enterprise/earthmaps/maps.html; [more here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/)) might be a possible solution. [The high usage limits seem promising](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/faq#pageview); you'll have to contact them for pricing, unfortunately. Still, it might be worth a look.
- **Bing Maps** - http://www.microsoft.com/maps/
- **Nokia Maps** - http://developer.here.net/

Comment: Thanks for the response.  These look promising.  I did look into MapBox, but the problem is it's a tiered pricing model, so while one of the tiers is within budget, the others aren't, and I really don't know what usage levels we'll need, which is why I wanted a fixed cost, to be safe.

Comment: Good to hear. For MapBox, at least all the options except Premium fall within your yearly budget. For example: Plus ($1788) and Standard ($588).

Comment: Unfortunately, I have NO usage statistics whatseover, so I don't even have a ballpark figure to go on.  So I'm faced with either making a call and risking going over budget or just playing it absolutely safe.  Also, IIRC their pricing is per tile, so it's actually more costly than it appears, but this is pretty standard for mapping services.

Comment: Wow, thanks!  Just about every mapping solution relies on a tile server and that may not be free.  So while these libraries may be free, whether or not the tile server is free is another matter.  Even OpenMaps -- which I thought was free -- isn't.  At least, their tile server is not.  The rest of it seems to be.  My head hurts :(.  I've been programming for years, I enjoy reading number theory texts in my spare time, yet nothing has confused me more than trying to understand the usage policies of ANY map service; free or otherwise.